# Understanding uniqueness in arrays of hashtables

Tags: powershell

Take this code, with output:

```
> (@(@{"number"=1},@{"number"=1},@{"number"=2})).Count
3
> (@(@{"number"=1},@{"number"=1},@{"number"=2}) | select -uniq).Count
1
```

I was expecting the second statement to return `2`. Clearly it doesn't but I don't understand the rationale for why not. Why does the `-uniq` option consider all of these three hashtables to be the same?

A follow on question, I want to remove duplicates from this:

```
@(@{"number"=1},@{"number"=1},@{"number"=2})
```

in order that the result is

```
@(@{"number"=1},@{"number"=2})
```

How do I do that?

Comment: The way you are creating this hashtable looks a little bit weird. Can you show tell us a little bit more about what you want to do?

Comment: Well its a fabricated example for the purposes of this post. Can you elucidate on why it looks weird?

Comment: Just because you are creating three hashtables with the same keys. I thought we can help you creating a PSCustomObject depending on your actual domain to improve your script. But I understand that it was for the purpose of this post so never mind

Comment: nevertheless that's a fair comment. Perhaps PSCustomObject is what I should be using. I admit I don't understand the justification of one over the other. I'm eager to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Sort-Object -Unique` instead of `Select-Object -Unique` if you want to evaluate the uniqueness of values but have the entire hashtable returned:

```
@(@{"number"=1},@{"number"=1},@{"number"=2}) | Sort-Object Values -Unique
```

Comment: Thanks. Still not understanding the rationale for why `select -uniq` doesn't do what i wanted but at least I now have something that works.

Comment: `Select -Unique` only evaluates the uniqueness of public NoteProperty members of the input object - a hash table has none, so they're all "equal" :)

Comment: OK, don't really understand what that means. I don't know what a noteProperty member is. To google I go :)

Comment: @jamiet Familiarize yourself with the `Get-Member` cmdlet, it can reveal some of what goes on "under the hood"

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify that you want the unique *apply to the values* of your hashtable:

```
(@(@{"number"=1},@{"number"=1},@{"number"=2}) | select Values -Unique).count
```

**Output:**

```
2
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, that explains how I can get a count of distinct values. Unfortunately it does not return the result that I want as explained above.

Comment: Yes, I was about posting this but Mathias already provided the answer :-)